# "Error: 'IplImage' does not name a type when trying to build darknet with OpenCV and CUDA?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, darknet

I am trying to use Darkent with OpenCV and CUDA. I installed darknet according to these instructions:

https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/

I installed CUDA according to these instructions:

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

Finally, I installed OpenCV according to these instructions:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/opencv.html

I then added the following lines to the end of my bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64:/usr/include/opencv4
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/include/opencv4
```

I was then having trouble with darknet finding the opencv library, so I added an opencv.pc file at /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig, with the following content:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir_new=${prefix}/include/opencv4

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 4.5.0
Libs: -L${libdir} -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core
Libs.private: -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt
Cflags: -I${includedir_new}
```

Next, I modified the Makefile in the darknet directory such that GPU=1, and OPENCV=1. I ran `make`, but am encountering the error:

```
./src/image_opencv.cpp:12:1: error: ‘IplImage’ does not name a type
   12 | IplImage *image_to_ipl(image im)
      | ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am running ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.4.0-53-generic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems there are some missing header lines in file `/src/image_opencv.cpp`, add these lines at the beginning than make it again.

```
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/videoio/legacy/constants_c.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
```

Additionally, you have to change the line `IplImage ipl = m` to `IplImage ipl = cvIplImage(m);` in the same file.

Comment: This fixed the original error, although now it is giving me the response: ```./src/image_opencv.cpp:64:20: error: conversion from ‘cv::Mat’ to non-scalar type ‘IplImage’ {aka ‘_IplImage’} requested
   64 |     IplImage ipl = m;``` I found someone with a similar issue here:
https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/1347 But the solution appears to be modifying the code more significantly. Maybe this is an issue with using a slightly wrong library version or something? It seems weird to have to signficiantly modify the example code. Thanks again!

Comment: I saw it too, but I don't think it needs all these modifications, you can simply use `IplImage ipl = cvIplImage(m);`.

Comment: Ok, that fixed that error, but now I have another one about 10 lines down in the same file: ```./src/image_opencv.cpp: In function ‘void* open_video_stream(const char*, int, int, int, int)’:
./src/image_opencv.cpp:77:20: error: ‘CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH’ was not declared in this scope
   77 |     if(w) cap->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w);
```

Comment: Googling this one, maybe I need an older version of opencv after all? Except that my coworker was able to get this same thing working without any of this trouble, using opencv 4.5, not sure what's different there

Comment: Add this library `#include "opencv2/videoio/legacy/constants_c.h"`.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your last comment. I added that, it fixed the current error. Now I have: `./src/image_opencv.cpp: In function ‘void make_window(char*, int, int, int)’:
./src/image_opencv.cpp:129:33: error: ‘CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN’ was not declared in this scope
  129 |         setWindowProperty(name, CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: Add this one too `#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"`, and I hope we face no more errors.

Comment: I edited your answer to include the other includes and edits you suggested here in the comments that fixed my problem

Answer (score 5):

For OpenCV4 users who are attempting to use OpenCV in darknet,

Reprinted from (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/darknet-compile-error-with-cudnn-8/141115/13): save the following in a file (patch.diff).

```
diff --git a/src/image_opencv.cpp b/src/image_opencv.cpp
index 7511280..c11805a 100644
--- a/src/image_opencv.cpp
+++ b/src/image_opencv.cpp
@@ -9,30 +9,34 @@ using namespace cv;

 extern "C" {
 
-IplImage *image_to_ipl(image im)
+Mat image_to_mat(image im)
 {
+    assert(im.c == 3 || im.c == 1);
     int x,y,c;
-    IplImage *disp = cvCreateImage(cvSize(im.w,im.h), IPL_DEPTH_8U, im.c);
-    int step = disp->widthStep;
+    image copy = copy_image(im);
+    constrain_image(copy);
+    if(im.c == 3) rgbgr_image(copy);
+    Mat m(im.h, im.w, CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, im.c));
     for(y = 0; y < im.h; ++y){
         for(x = 0; x < im.w; ++x){
             for(c= 0; c < im.c; ++c){
-                float val = im.data[c*im.h*im.w + y*im.w + x];
-                disp->imageData[y*step + x*im.c + c] = (unsigned char)(val*255);
+                float val = copy.data[c*im.h*im.w + y*im.w + x];
+                m.data[y*im.w*im.c + x*im.c + c] = (unsigned char)(val*255);
             }
         }
     }
-    return disp;
+    free_image(copy);
+    return m;
 }

-image ipl_to_image(IplImage* src)
+image mat_to_image(Mat m)
 {
-    int h = src->height;
-    int w = src->width;
-    int c = src->nChannels;
+    int h = m.rows;
+    int w = m.cols;
+    int c = m.channels();
     image im = make_image(w, h, c);
-    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *)src->imageData;
-    int step = src->widthStep;
+    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*)m.data;
+    int step = m.step;
     int i, j, k;

     for(i = 0; i < h; ++i){
@@ -42,26 +46,6 @@ image ipl_to_image(IplImage* src)
             }
         }
     }
-    return im;
-}
-
-Mat image_to_mat(image im)
-{
-    image copy = copy_image(im);
-    constrain_image(copy);
-    if(im.c == 3) rgbgr_image(copy);
-
-    IplImage *ipl = image_to_ipl(copy);
-    Mat m = cvarrToMat(ipl, true);
-    cvReleaseImage(&ipl);
-    free_image(copy);
-    return m;
-}
-
-image mat_to_image(Mat m)
-{
-    IplImage ipl = m;
-    image im = ipl_to_image(&ipl);
     rgbgr_image(im);
     return im;
 }
@@ -72,9 +56,9 @@ void *open_video_stream(const char *f, int c, int w, int h, int fps)
     if(f) cap = new VideoCapture(f);
     else cap = new VideoCapture(c);
     if(!cap->isOpened()) return 0;
-    if(w) cap->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w);
-    if(h) cap->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, w);
-    if(fps) cap->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, w);
+    if(w) cap->set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w);
+    if(h) cap->set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, w);
+    if(fps) cap->set(CAP_PROP_FPS, w);
     return (void *) cap;
 }

@@ -123,7 +107,7 @@ void make_window(char *name, int w, int h, int fullscreen)
 {
     namedWindow(name, WINDOW_NORMAL); 
     if (fullscreen) {
-        setWindowProperty(name, CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
+        setWindowProperty(name, WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
     } else {
         resizeWindow(name, w, h);
         if(strcmp(name, "Demo") == 0) moveWindow(name, 0, 0);
```

Run `git apply patch.diff`.